# C Makefile compilation error - "linker input file unused because linking not done"

Tags: c, bash, makefile

I'm having a problem with a C Makefile.

This is the code for the Makefile in bash:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
CCLINK=$(CC)
OBJS=flight.o runway.o airport.o main.o
RM=rm -f

# Creating the executable (airport)
airport: $(OBJS)
    $(CCLINK) -o airport $(OBJS)

# Creating object files using default rules
main.o: main.c airport.h ex2.h flight.h runway.h
airport.o: airport.c airport.h ex2.h flight.h runway.h
runway.o: runway.c runway.h ex2.h flight.h
flight.o: flight.c flight.h ex2.h

# Cleaning old files before new make
clean:
    $(RM) airport *.o *.bak *~ "#"* core
```

When I make the file, it says that:

```
make: `airport` is up to date.
```

After that - I can call "airport" in bash and it lets me enter some inputs the way I want it to be.

BUT- when I'm trying to check if "airport" is compiled by:

```
gcc -g -Wall -c airport
```

I get an error says that:

```
gcc: airport: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Does someone know what could be the problem?

Thanks!
Gavriel.

Comment: What do you mean by *when I'm trying to check if "airport" is compiled by:* ?

Comment: Hum, it seams you are trying to compile your executable...

Comment: Yes, try `gcc -g -Wall -c airport.c`             with a **.c**      Also, when you are issuing that `gcc` command, the makefile is not used *at all*. So this question has maybe is not about make, actually. But we all started learning this stuff at some point. There is a difference between *make* / *gcc* / *ld* and so on. Good luck with your programming! :)

Comment: Thank you all, I had a misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 1):

The aim of `Makefile` is to avoid recompiling a file if its source is unchanged; when it happens, `make` says that the file is up to date.

This might be annoying if you want to check again the warnings. Then, simply call `make` to recompile everything, by typing

```
make clean ; make
```

Another goal of `Makefile` is to avoid typing the `gcc` commands by yourself, prone to errors. For instance, at the end of your question, you ask to make an object file from an executable (option `-c`), which is wrong. The good way to make an object file is to call `make` :

```
make airport.o
```

Finally, to produce the executable, you can either type

```
make airport
```

or, since `airport:` is the first target, type

```
make
```